# rotate display in Simulator for tvOS app

Tags: xcode, tvos, simulator

I have a react native app that will be deployed to tvOS. Currently, I am building with the help of Apple's `Simulator`.

It is stuck in landscape mode, and the TV that will be deployed to is in portrait mode.

I cannot rotate the Simulator to portrait mode though, and I am stuck. I have spent an hour or so googling around and I cannot find an answer to how to rotate my tvOS app. The option is in `Hardware > Rotate Left` but it is greyed out.

[image: tvOS rotate greyed out]

How can I rotate my tvOS app 90 degrees?

Comment: I really hope there is answer to this. I don't want to build the entire app sideways...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least so far, with tvOS 10.2. Only landscape orientation is supported by AppleTv.

As you can see, the definition of UIDeviceOrientation is flagged as __TVOS_PROHIBITED

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSInteger, UIDeviceOrientation) {
    UIDeviceOrientationUnknown,
    UIDeviceOrientationPortrait,            // Device oriented vertically, home button on the bottom
    UIDeviceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown,  // Device oriented vertically, home button on the top
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft,       // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the right
    UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight,      // Device oriented horizontally, home button on the left
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceUp,              // Device oriented flat, face up
    UIDeviceOrientationFaceDown             // Device oriented flat, face down
} __TVOS_PROHIBITED;
```

Comment: sigh. I guess apple enjoys their features. Thanks for the info David.